# How load RL Unplugged data for torch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to use the RL Unplugged dataset, i.e. the episodes from [Cartpole swingup](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/rl_unplugged/dm_control_suite_episodes/cartpole_swingup?pageState=(%22StorageObjectListTable%22:(%22f%22:%22%255B%255D%22))&prefix=&forceOnObjectsSortingFiltering=false). How do I load this into torch? I assume this is a compressed `TensorSlice` or something similar but I cannot find any info on it.